# has_one :through and has_many :through in the same association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to model a relationship between Image model and Page model with the following constraints:

1 - a page can have a maximum of one image ( 0 image is also acceptable )

2 - an image is can appear in many pages.

so the relationship could be surmised as following:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_many :pages, :through :imageables
end

class Page < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_one :image, :through :imageables
end

class Imageable < ActiveRecord :: Base
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :page
end
```

Usually this associations either exist with both classes Image and Page with has_many :through or both having has_one :through 
Is it possible to mix between has_one :through and has_many :through in this case ? ActiveRecord does not mention this particular case

P.S: I chose to use the join model way since i have other models that could have the same images as well with different constraints (has_many instead of has_one)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You really shouldn't use a join model for this, regardless of whether it's used elsewhere.  Your page should have an `image_id` and a `belongs_to :image`. You can have many-to-many relationships elsewhere without needing to impose a join model on your page class.

Comment: Well the point is that a there are a lot of models that have the same  need as Page ( Article, Memo, Comment...). So i thought this is a cleaner way of specifying a relationship, instead of running migrations for all the models... Those are my personal thoughts, but i'm asking here to learn from your experience...

Comment: @user3442206 - Use polymorphic relationship for those: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: @BroiseSatse - Yes, i will use this in Imageable class. But for this example i tried to keep the code simple.. Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "mix has_one :through and has_many :through"?

Comment: @rossta: I'll reformulate my question. Is it possible to use the implementation above ? Without any draw backs ? The point is that i didn't see this in the ActiveRecord documentation, and the only example of the has_one :through, is within one-to-one association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above didn't work... And i found a median solution to implement the schema that i needed.

The final code looks like :

```
class Image < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_many :pages, :through :imageables
end

class Page < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_many :image, :through :imageables
  accepts_nested_attributes :images, allow_destroy => true
end

class Imageable < ActiveRecord :: Base
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :page
  validates_uniqueness_of :page_id
end
```

When i use rails_admin to edit my models, i get just the thing when it comes to add a new image and the validation in Imageable ensure the ditor do not mess around with the specifications...

It is little bit weird as a solution, but believe me, it is well adapted for the context of the app that i am developping...

I am posting it so if somebody had similar concern.